# VBA code to copy columns A:L only to another sheet (not entire column)

Tags: vba, excel

I have a spreadsheet where I enter a persons details in columns A-J and then indicate Yes in column K if he/she is referred for ASD 5P or column L for ASD PD. When I enter 'Yes' in one or both of those columns, I want to copy columns A:L of that row over to the relevant tab. I have the following code which copies the entire row over, but I want it to stop at column L. Here is the code I've been using (copied and adapted from various sites). Can anyone help me to amend this please?!?
[image: This is what my spreadsheet looks like]

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range

    Set KeyCells = Range("K:L")

    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
           Is Nothing Then

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    Dim x As Long
    x = 3
    Dim rng As Range
    For Each rng In Sheets("Sheet1").Range("K3:K" & LastRow)
        If rng = "Yes" Then
            rng.EntireRow.Copy Sheets("ASD 5P").Cells(x, 1)
            x = x + 1
            ActiveSheet.Range("A3:Q200").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(4, 5, 6), Header:=xlNo
        End If
    Next rng
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True


    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    LastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    x = 3
    For Each rng In Sheets("Sheet1").Range("L3:L" & LastRow)
        If rng = "Yes" Then
            rng.EntireRow.Copy Sheets("ASD PD").Cells(x, 1)
            x = x + 1
            ActiveSheet.Range("A3:Q200").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(4, 5, 6), Header:=xlNo
        End If
    Next rng
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You can use `Sheets("Sheet1").cells(rng.row,1).resize(,12).Copy Sheets("ASD 5P").Cells(x, 1)`.

Comment: Can you please advise where I fit this into my code please? Sorry, I'm new to VBA and don't want to ruin what I've done so far.

Comment: I am just replacing your current `rng.EntireRow.Copy ...` lines.

Comment: By the way, I'm not sure you need two loops, you could do both checks in one.

Comment: That's it. Thank you!!!

Comment: If you can recommend how to do both checks in one, that would be great. I also need to ensure that I don't end up with duplicates appearing in the destination sheets, so each person only gets added once to each list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggested re-write (too long to fit in the comments!). Am also not sure you need to remove duplicates in your loop, but have left in as not sure what it does.

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim KeyCells As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim x As Long, y As Long
Dim rng As Range

Set KeyCells = Range("K:L")

If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    LastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    x = 3: y = 3

    For Each rng In Sheets("Sheet1").Range("K3:K" & LastRow)
        If rng = "Yes" Then
            Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(rng.Row, 1).Resize(, 12).Copy Sheets("ASD 5P").Cells(x, 1)
            x = x + 1
            ActiveSheet.Range("A3:Q200").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(4, 5, 6), Header:=xlNo
        End If
        If rng.Offset(, 1) = "Yes" Then
            Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(rng.Row, 1).Resize(, 12).Copy Sheets("ASD PD").Cells(y, 1)
            y = y + 1
            ActiveSheet.Range("A3:Q200").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(4, 5, 6), Header:=xlNo
        End If
    Next rng
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  Dim KeyCells As Range

  Set KeyCells = Range("K:L")

  If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
       Is Nothing Then

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Dim LastRow As Long
  LastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
  Dim x As Long
  x = 3
  Dim rng As Range
  For Each rng In Sheets("Sheet1").Range("K3:L" & LastRow)
      If rng = "Yes" Then
          Range("A" & rng.row & ":L" & rng.row).Copy Sheets("ASD 5P").Cells(x, 1)
          x = x + 1
          ActiveSheet.Range("A3:Q200").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(4, 5, 6), Header:=xlNo
      End If
  Next rng
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True

  End If
  End Sub
```

Comment: I just rechecked your code and realized that I shouldn't have removed the second loop.    The Range(...).Copy bit can be used for both loops though.